# Inter process communication for transferring tree structure

Tags: c#, c++, xml, ipc

I want to transfer a tree of UI objects from process A to B.  i.e. Process B want to know the layout of windows in process A. 
 I found below link nearly what I need, but the method in this link can only transfer objects with well-defined structure. 
 [link](https://www.google.co.jp/amp/s/coders-corner.net/2014/04/20/inter-process-communication-with-anonymous-pipes-part-02-transfer-an-object/amp/)

While I am going to transfer tree structure: I do not know the layout beforehand.

Can anyone give me some hints? thanks a lot!

Comment: You already tagged this question XML. XML is a good way to represent tree structures.

Comment: It seems memory mapped file is a good alternative to pipe, but I did not find good examples which make it easy to pack and unpack the UI layout information. I feel XML over memory mapped file is a good choice, but did not find a sample.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can I transfer XML file over pipe? If not, is it possible to transfer XML memory object over pipe? I want to avoid access to disk, to get good performance.

Comment: @GangLi What makes you think the content format plays any role for the way you transmit a file between two processes?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ XML format is easy to use since there are good libraries to handle XML format. If I use a format defined by myself, I have to write the library part myself.

Comment: What does you tree look like?  It should contain a root MyClass with either a List<MyClass> children, or a MyClass left and MyClass right.  The you need to use a recursive method to call  SerializeToXml and add results to xml.  Pretty simple.  Post a sample of your tree class and I will help.

Comment: @jdweng thank you so much, but I do not know the tree structure, because the A process has many windows which contain many controls. I want process B to know the UI layout of process A at any given time. My final goal is a test automation tool which is smart enough to “know” UI layout of process A any time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you project would look like the code below.  You may need a custom serializer or to create a tree from your process that fills in the windows and controls.  Not sure from you description what is the best way of proceeding.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();

            XDocument doc = new XDocument("root");

            XElement xProcess = SerializeToXml<Process>.Serialize(process);
            doc.Add(xProcess);

        }

    }

    public class SerializeToXml <T>
    {
        public static XElement Serialize(T data)
        {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings);


            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());

            serializer.Serialize(xWriter, data);

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xWriter.ToString());

            writer.Close();

            return (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
        } 
    }
    public class Process
    {
        public List<Window> windows { get; set; }
    }
    public class Window
    {
        public List<Control> controls { get; set; }
    }
    public class Control
    {
    }
}
```